# In Tcl: Set -eofchar to windows / unix respectively

Tags: windows, unix, tcl, newline

I am writing an mini application which always will run on windows. 
It has two tasks:

1. Read a text file originating from a unix system and output a new file with the same content but with windows file ending.
2. Read a text file from a windows system and output a new file with the same content but with unix file ending.

The channel input end of line should always be handled automatically from tcl.

-eofchar however expects two aruments, one for in and one for output. What do I have to pass as an argument to -eofchar to fulfill task 1 and what to fulfill task 2?

My code for the make windows eof proc:

```
proc MakeWin {} {
    # read file

    set types {
        {{All Files}        *             }
    }
    set filename [tk_getOpenFile -filetypes $types]
    set infile [open $filename]

    # open file for writing

    set PathWname [tk_getSaveFile -filetypes $types -initialdir $DefPath -title "Save Results as:"]
    set outfile [open $PathWname w]

    # chan configure $outfile -eofchar  ?? 
    #
    while {[gets $infile line] >= 0} {
        puts $outfile $line
    }
    close $infile
    close $outfile
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form the [manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M12):

> **-eofchar char**
>
> **-eofchar {inChar outChar}**
>
> This option supports DOS file systems that use Control-z (\x1a) as an end of file marker. If char is not an empty string, then this character signals end-of-file when it is encountered during input. For output, the end-of-file character is output when the channel is closed. If char is the empty string, then there is no special end of file character marker. For read-write channels, a two-element list specifies the end of file marker for input and output, respectively. As a convenience, when setting the end-of-file character for a read-write channel you can specify a single value that will apply to both reading and writing. When querying the end-of-file character of a read-write channel, a two-element list will always be returned. The default value for -eofchar is the empty string in all cases except for files under Windows. In that case the -eofchar is Control-z (\x1a) for reading and the empty string for writing. The acceptable range for -eofchar values is \x01 - \x7f; attempting to set -eofchar to a value outside of this range will generate an error.

I read this as saying that to read a windows file and write UNIX, you needn't do anything - `-eofchar` is `\x1a` for input and `""` for output by default on Windows. To read a UNIX file and write windows, do

```
chan configure $infile -eofchar ""
chan configure $outfile -eofchar \x1a
```

There doesn't appear to be any need to specify input *and* output `eofchar`s if the channel is opened unidirectionally.

*Disclaimer*: This is based on reading the manpage; I've never done this kind of thing myself.

Comment: I use \x1a  (Ctr-z) to write out in Windows style (is the same as or \x1a\x0d).  To write out in Unix style i use \x0a expecting to only get a linefeed. But when i look in the file using notepad++ i still see a CR and a LF. Why ?

Comment: I don't follow. How is `\x1a` the same as `x1a\x0d`? One is a single character, the other is two. When do you _use \x0a_ to write in UNIX style? If you are concerned about line endings - and you should be - look at the `chan configure -translation` [manpage](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M12) and/or ask another question.

Comment: It should be noted that `source` always sets the `-eofchar` to `\x1a` (on its internally-used channel) on _all_ platforms. Don't put a literal `^Z` in your Tcl scripts.